# Do I need to explicitly create a cancellation token source with IHostedService?

Tags: c#, .net, ihostedservice

Is the internal implementation of the library supplying me with a cancellation token source, or do I need to create my own?

I'm reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice.executeasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and it seems like I would need to create my own source in the caller method, then pass the token to the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the internal implementation of the library supplying me with a cancellation token source, or do I need to create my own?

No, you will not be getting `CancellationTokenSource`, only `CancelationToken`'s for `StartAsync`/`StopAsync` methods (to support graceful shutdown/interruption, [some docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#ihostedservice-interface)).

If need to cancel call to some service additionally you will need to create your own `CancellationTokenSource` via `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`. Something along these lines:

```cs
class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
        cts.CancelAfter(1000); // for example

        _ = someService.DoAsync(cts.Token);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
        cts.CancelAfter(1000); // for example

        await anotherService.DoAsync(cts.Token);
    }
}
```

**If you don't have custom cancellation logic then using passed `cancellationToken` is enough.**

Also consider using [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class) base class, it encapsulates some of usual hosted service boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `AddHostedService<T>` extension method to add the service, then it will be supplied with a stopping token that will be cancelled if/when the host is gracefully terminated.

If for some reason you are calling the service through some other manual approach (i.e. testing), then you would want to provide it a cancellation token.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionhostedserviceextensions.addhostedservice